# Get Project Structure from Eclipse?

Tags: java, javascript, json, eclipse

I have an eclipse project with lots and lots of packages and `.java` files. I was wondering if it is able to retrieve the project structure in some text form / json form from eclipse?

```
Package1
     java1
        method1
        method2
        method3
        ...

     java2
        ...


    ...

Package2
    ...
```

Like that in a json/text file?

Is it possible using eclipse? Or should I actually write a code that prunes the project directory and recursively build the file structure?

I'm trying to do this so that I can visualize the project hierarchy using this **D3.js** tool:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: Have a look at ant4eclipse.

Comment: Maybe javadoc can help you out.

Comment: I'm curious: what do you want to do with this structure?

Comment: Visualize it using this: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using windows? Just enter `tree yourProjectFolder /F /A > output.txt` in the commandline

Comment: That's a good one! But it won't give me the methods inside a `.java`. I need the methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code below can help you.

It will print every folder and every file it founds. If the file is a `*.java`, the code enters it and prints everything that matches a java method.

Also, if needed, change the REGEX that determines what is a method. The line is:

```
public static final String JAVA_METHOD_REGEX = "(public|protected|private|static|\\s) +[\\w\\<\\>\\[\\]]+\\s+(\\w+) *\\([^\\)]*\\)";
```

Full code:

```
public class ReadFilesAndMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File folder = new File("C:/Workspace/MyProject/src");
        listFiles(folder, "");
    }

    public static final String JAVA_FILE_REGEX = "^\\w+\\.java";
    public static final String JAVA_METHOD_REGEX = "(public|protected|private|static|\\s) +[\\w\\<\\>\\[\\]]+\\s+(\\w+) *\\([^\\)]*\\)";

    public static void listFiles(File folder, String prefix) throws Exception {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(prefix + fileEntry.getName() + "/");
                listFiles(fileEntry, prefix + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.println(prefix + fileEntry.getName());
                if (fileEntry.getName().matches(JAVA_FILE_REGEX)) {
                    readMethodsFromJavaFile(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), prefix + "\t");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void readMethodsFromJavaFile(String fileName, String prefix) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        scanner.close();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(JAVA_METHOD_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(prefix+matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
main/
    java/
        utils/
            UsefulStuff.java
                public Long getSomething(Class<?> classe)
                public Whatever load(String anything)
            Start.java
                static void main(String[] args)
        entity/
            system/
                User.java
                    public long getId()
                    public void setId(long id)
...
```